# Angular data binding with calculation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

This seems like a pretty simple question but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

When using data binding in AngularJS as such:

```
<iframe height="{{bodyHeight}}"> </iframe>
```

I just want to subtract a number from `bodyHeight` similar to:

```
<iframe height="{{bodyHeight - 90}}"> </iframe>
```

I was hoping to do so without using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. bodyHeight was being passed in as a number with `px` on the end like: `1280px`.

So I just changed it to `1280` then the data binding is:

```
<iframe height="{{bodyHeight - 90}}px"> </iframe>
```

Pretty silly but I'll leave this here anyways for reference.

Answer (score 2):

What you have actually works!

You are able to do calculations and other javascript within angularJS's `{{ }}` data-binding!

From the [angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> Angular expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually
> placed in bindings such as {{ expression }}.
>
> For example, these are valid expressions in Angular:
>
> **1+2**
>
> **a+b**
>
> **user.name**
>
> **items[index]**